# Caffeine Cache - Specify expiry for an entry

Tags: java, caffeine

I'm trying to further my understanding of the [caffeine cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). I was wondering if there is a way to specify a timeout for an entry that's populated in the cache, but have no time based expiry for the rest of the records.

Essentially I would like to have the following interface:

`put(key, value, timeToExpiry)`// enter a key and value with a specified timeToExpiry

`put(key, value)` // enter a key value with no timeToExpiry

I can write the interfaces and plumbing, but I'd like to understand how I can configure caffeine for both of the above requirements. I'm also open to have two separate instances of the caffeine cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done by using a custom expiration policy and leverage an unreachable duration. The maximum duration is `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which is 292 years in nanoseconds. Assuming your record holds when (and if) it expires then you might configure the cache as,

```java
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfter(new Expiry<Key, Graph>() {
      public long expireAfterCreate(Key key, Graph graph, long currentTime) {
        if (graph.getExpiresOn() == null) {
          return Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        long seconds = graph.getExpiresOn()
            .minus(System.currentTimeMillis(), MILLIS)
            .toEpochSecond();
        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(seconds);
      }
      public long expireAfterUpdate(Key key, Graph graph, 
          long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
      public long expireAfterRead(Key key, Graph graph,
          long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
    })
    .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, this helps create the initial graph with a 292 year timeout, but would it be possible to also do something along the lines of 
`put(key,value, timeToExpiry)`, where you specify the time to expiry when you are putting the value in the cache?

Comment: Yes, see `cache.policy()` for these types of ad hoc methods. You can set the default expiry to be infinite and use `VarExpiration#put(key, value, duration)` for an explicit setting. The callback approach is preferred over racy get-load-put because it lets the cache handle [cache stampedes](https://doordash.engineering/2018/08/03/avoiding-cache-stampede-at-doordash/) for you.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get expiry for an entry? and override if need

Comment: @psyskeptic `VarExpiration#getExpiresAfter(key)` and `setExpiresAfter(key, duration)`.

Comment: Hi, is there any `package/plugin` available to apply the same approach for the `NodeJs` project?

Comment: @Mani There is a TypeScript [cache](https://github.com/aholstenson/transitory) and [timer-wheel](https://github.com/aholstenson/timer-wheel) that ported concepts and code from Caffeine. I don't know that ecosystem, only that this one was inspired by the Java project.

Comment: Thank you @BenManes, I hope this will help me.

Comment: `private LoadingCache<String, Object> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
  .expireAfter(new Expiry<String, Object>() {
    @Override
      public long expireAfterCreate(String key, Object obj, long currentTime) {
        if (obj.getExpiresOn() == null) {
          return Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        long seconds = obj.getExpiresOn()
        .minus(System.currentTimeMillis(), MILLIS)
        .toEpochSecond();
        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(seconds);  }
`<br/> @BenManes How is the .getExpiresOn() defined?

Comment: @MartinVanNostrand That example was if you could derive the custom expiration from the value. For example, Google lets you cache address<->geocode resolutions for 30 days. You could store that in your db record and in-memory cache would know to expire to honor that. Similar if an http response etag. That's for you to figure out, else you can give constant values if a static configuration.

Comment: `@Bean
    public Cache<String, Oauth2Token> sapOauth2Cache(){
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .initialCapacity(100)
                .maximumSize(1000)
                .expireAfter(new CustomExpiryForOauth())
                .build();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the subject, I am inspired by this few articles, and I share with you the solution that worked well for me.

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CaffeineConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;


  @Bean
  public Caffeine caffeineConfig() {
    return Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfter(new Expiry<String, Object>() {
      @Override
      public long expireAfterCreate(String key, Object value, long currentTime) {
        long customExpiry = applicationProperties.getCache().getEhcache().getTimeToLiveSeconds();
        if (key.startsWith("PREFIX")) {
          customExpiry = 60;
        }
        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(customExpiry);
      }

      @Override
      public long expireAfterUpdate(String key, Object value, long currentTime,
          long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }

      @Override
      public long expireAfterRead(String key, Object value, long currentTime,
          long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
    });

  }


  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine caffeine) {
    CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
    caffeineCacheManager.getCache(PROVIDER_RESPONSE);
    caffeineCacheManager.getCache(BCU_RESPONSE);
    caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);
    return caffeineCacheManager;
  }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If anyones still looking for this, here is one comfy wrapper using Ben Manes earlier response. (in kotlin though, should be easily convertible to java)

```
class DynamicTTLCache<K, V>(
initialCapacity: Int,
maxCapacity: Long,
private val defaultTTLInMillis: Long = Long.MAX_VALUE) {

inner class CacheValue(
    val value: V,
    val ttlInMillis: Long
)

val cache: Cache<K, CacheValue> = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .initialCapacity(initialCapacity)
    .expireAfter(object : Expiry<K, CacheValue> {
        override fun expireAfterCreate(k: K?, v: DynamicTTLCache<K, V>.CacheValue?, currentTime: Long): Long {
            return v?.ttlInMillis?.let { TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(it) } ?: defaultTTLInMillis
        }
        override fun expireAfterUpdate(k: K?, v: DynamicTTLCache<K, V>.CacheValue?,
                                       currentTime: Long, currentDuration: Long): Long {
            return currentDuration
        }
        override fun expireAfterRead(k: K?, v: DynamicTTLCache<K, V>.CacheValue?,
                                     currentTime: Long, currentDuration: Long): Long {
            return currentDuration
        }
    })
    .maximumSize(maxCapacity)
    .build()

fun put(key: K, value: V, ttlInMillis: Long?) {
    cache.put(key, CacheValue(value, ttlInMillis?: defaultTTLInMillis))
}

fun getIfPresent(key: K): V? {
    return cache.getIfPresent(key)?.value
}}
```