# How to add a dynamic ttl on a per entry basis to Caffeine cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, caffeine-cache

I want to provide a method with the signature-

```
`public void addObjectToCacheWithExpiry(CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager, String cacheName, String key, Object value, long duration, TimeUnit timeUnit)`
```

So that I can put a value inside the specific cache with the duration passed as an arg.

Some explanation was offered here by Ben [Caffeine Cache - Specify expiry for an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61721386/caffeine-cache-specify-expiry-for-an-entry)

```
`.  @Override
    public void addObjectToCacheWithExpiry(CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager, String cacheName, String key, Object value, long duration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        CaffeineCache caffeineCache = (CaffeineCache) caffeineCacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
        Cache<Object, Object> nativeCache = caffeineCache.getNativeCache();
        Policy.VarExpiration varExpiration = (Policy.VarExpiration) nativeCache.policy().expireVariably().get();
        varExpiration.put(key, value, duration, timeUnit);`
    }
```

I couldn't follow the whole thing. It mentions that we can use cache.policy() to get Policy.VarExpiration interface which provides access to the method I needed. To that end, I added the following code-

In principle this is what I wanted. However, when I get the nativeCache object it doesn't show up with a policy(policy = null). This prevents me from using it to put object since it just returns NPE. How should I tackle this?
[null policy for empty map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usMA8.png)

Adding the config for CaffeineCache-

```
`   `@Bean
    public CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager(Caffeine caffeine){
        CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);
        return caffeineCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Caffeine CaffeineCacheConfig() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .initialCapacity(1000)
                .maximumSize(1200);
    }`
`
```

Comment: Did you try calling the `policy()` method? The field is lazily allocated, just like how `HashMap` lazily initializes its `keySet` and related views.

Comment: I think I was able to resolve this. I wasn't implementing the expireAfter property. Once I did, it started working. From documentation as well it mentions that these specific policies are accessible if you support them at the time of construction. I am adding my own answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work. From the documentation -

> /**    * Returns access to perform operations based on the variable
> expiration policy. This policy    * determines that an entry should be
> automatically removed from the cache once a per-entry    * duration
> has elapsed.    *
>
> * If the cache was not constructed with
> variable expiration or the implementation does not    * support these
> operations, an empty {@link Optional} is returned.    *    * @return
> access to low-level operations for this cache if a variable expiration
> policy is used    */   @NonNull

Based on this, I removed `expireAfterWrite` property and instead implemented `expireAfter`. I was able to test that dynamic ttl with `VarExpiration.put` was working fine. I will update this answer after I have tested that a default of 5 min was also being applied in case of a missing ttl.

```java
@Bean
public <K,V> Caffeine<K, V> CaffeineCacheConfig() {
    return Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .initialCapacity(1000)
        .expireAfter(new Expiry<K , V>() {
            public long expireAfterCreate(K key, V graph, long currentTime) {
                // Use wall clock time, rather than nanotime, if from an external resource
                //return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
                log.info("Expire after create");
                return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5 * 60);
            }

            public long expireAfterUpdate(K key, V graph,
                long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
                return currentDuration;
            }
    
            public long expireAfterRead(K key, V graph,
                long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
                return currentDuration;
            }
        }
    ).maximumSize(1200)
     .evictionListener(((key, value, cause) -> {
          log.info("evicted key, value, cause : {} {} {}", key, value, cause);
      })).removalListener(((key, value, cause) -> {
          log.info("removed key, value, cause : {} {} {}", key, value, cause);
      }));
}
```